# How to handle "Permission Denied" Exception in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get name/path of all the files and directories present on an android device through my flutter app.

Below is the code used to get the desired data :

```
Directory(_storageInstance.rootDirectory).list(recursive: true).listen((event) {
          _storageInstance.searchList.add(SearchEntity(path: event.path,type: event.runtimeType.toString() == "_Directory" ? EntityType.DIRECTORY : EntityType.FILE));
        });
```

Now the issue I am facing is that devices having **API 30 or above** don't allow access to some specific directories like the 'data' and 'obb' Directories in the 'Android' Directory.
Hence in the above code whenever my Directory().list().listen() stream receives those directories, it throws the following exception :

```
E/flutter (28808): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter (28808):
E/flutter (28808): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

I tried adding try catch like this :

```
Directory(_storageInstance.rootDirectory).list(recursive: true).listen((event) {
          try{
            _storageInstance.searchList.add(SearchEntity(path: event.path,type: 
            event.runtimeType.toString() == "_Directory" ? EntityType.DIRECTORY : EntityType.FILE));
          }
          catch(e){
            print("Exception Caught");
          }
});
```

But it still is not able to handle the exception and throws the same exception as above.
Usually a simple try catch work ....... maybe I am using it properly in this scenario.

How can I properly handle the exception in this scenario ?

Thankyou in advance for answering :)

**UPDATE :**

I tried adding the permssions in Android Manifest.xml. But it still is throwing the same exceptions.

Below is the setting tab of the app :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you take permission by adding in ```androidmainifest.xml```?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane No can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Did u found the answer for it man ? I'm also facing same..

Answer (score 1):

Add this line inside `mainifest` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You have to add this line of code in `android/app/src/debug/AndroidMainifest.xml` which is for the debug version and in `android/app/src/main/AndroidMainifest.xml`.

So,

```
<manifest ...>
   // Here must be lots of other codes 

   // Paste those lines after all those codes, here just above </mainifest>
</manifest>
```

If that is still not clear. Here is a example of `AndroidMainifest.xml` from my project in `debug` directory.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.do_app">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

*Note:- You have to run from the start after you make those changes.

Comment: I tried the above steps ........ Also re installed the app and did a flutter clean ....But still giving the same exception

Comment: You added to both debug version and main?

Comment: yes I added all of these permissions in both manifests : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"/>

Comment: Can you check by going inside settings in app and check if we addedd permission successfully.

Comment: I have added the screenshots of the settings in my question ...... please have a look.

Comment: Yes I thought of it too .....Hence I checked the permission for all files. An re-opened the app after a flutter clean ......... But its still throwing those exceptions

Comment: I don't know more on this . I got the same problem few days ago. And, it solved the problem.

Comment: Is there any way that I can add a try catch around it and ignore the file causing the exceptions ?

Comment: I don't think so. As, what you need is permission which does not seem to be working

Comment: You saved my day!
I had <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
at `debug` part and not in the `main` section of the manifest. And it was really annoying: it works on my computer but customers could not connect to a server.